# grep IP adress with open port nmap

Tags: bash, grep

I'm trying to make this script to grep IP adresses with open port from nmap but I can't do it the right way.

I have something like this:

```
nmap 192.168.0.0/24 -sU -p 44555 | grep -oP "([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}"  >output.txt
```

But this is taking all IP's open and closed.

example output nmap:

```
Nmap scan report for 79-119-0-248.rdsnet.ro (79.119.0.248)
Host is up (0.033s latency).
PORT      STATE         SERVICE
27023/udp open|filtered unknown

Nmap scan report for 79-119-0-249.rdsnet.ro (79.119.0.249)
Host is up (0.032s latency).
PORT      STATE  SERVICE
27023/udp closed unknown
```

Only the ones are open/filtered I want
Thanks

Comment: Can you give the output of *nmap*?

Comment: I don't have on the network output yet so tried another range

Comment: I'm sorry I think I misunderstood you question: in the following case you only want the first ip?

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer by clicking the tick under the correct answer.

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer by clicking the tick under the correct answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Output IP only from an nmap scan on open port](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18130022/output-ip-only-from-an-nmap-scan-on-open-port)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works with *egrep* :

```
nmap 192.168.0.0/24 -sU -p 44555 | grep -B3 open | egrep -o "([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}"  > output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just get **open ip** you can try the following code(surely works):

```
nmap 192.168.0.0/24 -sU -p 44555 | grep '^44555.*open' -B3 | grep '^Nmap scan' | cut -d\( -f2 | cut -d\) -f1 > output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Using awk

```
nmap 192.168.0.0/24 -sU -p 44555|awk  '/(open|filtered)/{print $2}' RS="Nmap" FS="[)(]"
```

#### Explanation

- `RS="Nmap"` - set work `Nmap` as record Separator variable
- `FS="[)(]"`set parentheses as field separators
- `/(open|filtered)/{print $2}` If the record has `open` or `filtered`, print column 2.